# Can't connect to jack audio server when running Timidity

Tags: alsa, timidity

In order to run Guitar Pro 5.2 emulated on wine on Linux I need to run timidity so I can get the audio from the program. I followed instructions from [this tutorial](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/archlinux-wiki/wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Guitar_Pro.html) but when I run timidity it fails with the following erros:

```
$  timidity -iA 
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
Couldn't open output device
```

Currently I have installed Jack 0.125.0-8 and Timidity++ 2.15.0-2.

Comment: Do you have a Jack server running? If not, maybe -os is what you want